# Any chance that a while(1) thread gets killed without killing the process?

Tags: linux

I'd like to know if there is any chance that a thread executing any bad thing in a `while(1)` loop, gets killed by the kernel without the process gets informed.

I mean if the thread causes a `SIGSEGV`, the process is necessary affected so, that's not a case I'm interested in.

Comment: It's possible to handle `SIGSEGV` by installing signal handler, see `man signal` for details

Answer (score 0):

If it's killed by a `SIGKILL`:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Kernel may do that by itself in the case of Out of Memory (OOM) killer activation.

Comment: ok but it's a signal sent to the process, not to a particular thread. I was wondering if the kernel can kill a thread specifically, not the process.